# Как в проекте на django создать файл внутри функции представления и загрузить в бд

Tags: python, django

Подскажите, можно ли создать файл внутри функции представления или класса в django на основе приходящих данных и формы, и после загрузить этот файл в bd, чтобы он попадал не в корневую папку проекта, а в папку `медиа`? Прилагаю примеры, как я делаю:

```py
def forIndex(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        newText = request.POST["file"]
        newdata = Data()
        newdata.name = newText
        print(newText)
        with open("text.txt", "w") as file:
            data = file.write(newText)
            newdata.file = data
    return render(request, "new/index.html")
```

Comment: код в вопросе должен быть текстом.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/file-uploads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно переопределить метод `form_valid` в классе представления (CBV) и добавить свою логику.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    # дописать Вашу логику 
    self.object.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```